# Establishing a connection between a fedora machine and a distant server takes more than 10 seconds!

Tags: networking, fedora, ping

I've recently started dual booting Windows with Fedora, while working with Windows loading a web-page is fast (less than 3 seconds) so it's not a bandwidth problem while with fedora this will take more than 10 seconds!

I first thought the problem is related to Firefox since I'm not used to it, so I decided to ping `google.com` and found out that establishing the connection is what takes too long, before it starts pinging (this takes almost 70ms in my case which is normal, and BTW I did this multiple times so it's not a first ping problem)

Any thoughts will be appreciated

Comment: Is it slow for the name: `ping google.com` and one of their servers directly: `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Thanks @user1794469, the problem was related to DNS as you thought. I already solved the problem.

Comment: FYI, I've been using [`knot-resolver`](https://knot-resolver.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) on Fedora (29-32) for about a year now and have enjoyed my enhanced DNS experience.

Comment: Looks interesting, I will try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to anyone, who gave this question some of his time. After writing the question, I remembered that I have changed the DNS in my router, so I checked which dns is being used by my machine:
`cat /etc/resolve.conf`

and found that it is the one defined in my router, I changed it with 8.8.8.8 and now it's working as expected.